# javascript adding new buildings

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm not sure how to add a new building by array. I'm a beginner javascript person.

I added saving/loading among other things to the back end but the client side is giving me issues for some reason.

I think it has something to do with me not under standing arrays correctly but if you could point me in the right direction i would love to learn.

I want to add a second building called

```
loadbuilding("taco stand")
```

Here is the code:

```js
var Timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    Tick()
}, 1000);
var buildings = [];

//The object declaration for game saves
function GameSave() {
    this.money = 0;
    this.buildings = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
        this.buildings[i] = 0;
    }
}

//The object declaration for buildings
function Building() {
    this.Name = "Lemonade Stand";
    this.Cost = 10;
    this.PerSec = 1;
}

//The function to initialise all buildings
function InitBuildings() {
    LoadBuilding("Lemonade Stand", 10, 1);
    LoadBuilding("Taco Stand", 100, 1);

}

//The function to automatically load a building into the buildings array
function LoadBuilding(name, cost, persec) {
    var cur = buildings.length;

    buildings[cur] = new Building();
    buildings[cur].Name = name;
    buildings[cur].Cost = cost;
    buildings[cur].PerSec = persec;
}

//The function used to gather money
function GatherMoney() {
    game.money++; //++ tells javascript to add 1 to the variable

    //Display the player's current money
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = game.money;
}

//The function that gets run every second
function Tick() {
    for (var i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
        game.money += game.buildings[i] * buildings[i].PerSec;
    }
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = game.money;
}

//The function to buy a lemonade stand
function Build(id) {
    if (game.money >= buildings[id].Cost) { //Check if the player has enough money, then subtract it and add a new building if they do
        game.money -= buildings[id].Cost;
        game.buildings[id] = game.buildings[id] + 1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = game.money;
        document.getElementById("Building1Qty").innerHTML = game.buildings[id];
    }
}

//Run this code once the page has loaded fully
window.onload = function() {
    InitBuildings();
    window.game = new GameSave();
};
```

```html
<!--Pleae refer to Lesson 9.txt for a full description on this lesson -->

<html>
<head>
<title>Basic Incremental Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Incremental.css">
<script src="js/Incremental.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="page">
  <div id="header">
   <div id="game-title">
    Basic Incremental Game
   </div>
  </div>
 
 <div id="content">
  <div id="stats" class="block">
   <div class="label">Money:</div>
   <div id="money" class="label">0</div>
  </div>
 
  <div id="clickables" class="block">
   <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="GatherMoney();">
  </div>
 
  <div id="buildings" class="block">
   <div id="Building1">
    <input type="button" value="Lemonade Stand" onclick="Build(0);">
    <div>
     <div class="label">Cost:</div>
     <div id="Building1Cost" class="label">10</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
     <div class="label">Per Sec:</div>
     <div id="Building1PerSec" class="label">1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
     <div class="label">Quantity:</div>
     <div id="Building1Qty" class="label">0</div>
    </div>
   </div>
     <div id="Building2">
    <input type="button" value="Taco Stand" onclick="Build(1);">
    <div>
     <div class="label">Cost:</div>
     <div id="Building2Cost" class="label">10</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
     <div class="label">Per Sec:</div>
     <div id="Building2PerSec" class="label">1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div>
     <div class="label">Quantity:</div>
     <div id="Building2Qty" class="label">0</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <div id="upgrades" class="block">
   This is where our upgrades will go!
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

EDIT:

i tried changing the but tit didnt work

```
buildings[]
```

to

```
buildings["Lemonade Stand", "Taco Stand"]
```

Comment: Put your code in the question. If you are going to provide links, please make them clickable.

Comment: i made them clickable i'm sorry

Comment: For one thing, in your GameSave function, change `this.buildings[i] = 0;` to `this.buildings[i] = buildings[i];`

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
LoadBuilding("myBuilding", 12, 1);
```

Because you have this factory function,

```
function LoadBuilding(name, cost, persec) {
    var cur = buildings.length;

    buildings[cur] = new Building();
    buildings[cur].Name = name;
    buildings[cur].Cost = cost;
    buildings[cur].PerSec = persec;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work but i googled what is a factory function. i need to redo the code it drasticly..

Comment: what are you getting when you console.log(buildings) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could build an array of Building objects then iterate through them using a while loop.

See [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/ekb5u2ts/), or attached code.

Let me know if that helps.

```js
class Building {
 constructor(name, cost, persec) {
  this.name = name;
  this.cost = cost;
  this.persec = persec;
 }
}

var buildings = [];

buildings.push(new Building('Building One', '$10', '1'));
buildings.push(new Building('Building Two', '$20', '0.5'));
buildings.push(new Building('Building Three', '$25', '2'));

var count = 0;

while(count < buildings.length) {
 document.getElementById('stores').innerHTML += '<p>' + buildings[count].name + '<br />' + buildings[count].cost + '<br />' + buildings[count].persec + '</p>';
  count++;
}
```

```html
<div id="stores">

</div>
```